# Gatsby SVG with <use> not working with gastby build

Tags: javascript, typescript, gatsby

I created some SVG sprites/symbols to be able to use icon as component and with `gatsby develop` and it works fine (img below).

[image: Working example of SVG Sprites]

Problem is when i try to build my Gatsby application with `gatsby build` SVG icons are not showing (img below).

[image: Broken example with gatsby build]

Anyone has idea what am I missing?

My Icon component:

```
import { IconTypes } from "./types";
import Icons from "./icons.svg";

interface Props {
  name: IconTypes;
  className?: string;
  width?: number;
  height?: number;
  fill?: string;
}

export const Icon: FC<Props> = ({ name, className, width, height, fill }) => {
  return (
    <svg className={className} width={width} height={height} fill={fill}>
      <use href={`${Icons}#${name}`} />
    </svg>
  );
};
```

Comment: I moved everything to one single file for this: https://iconmeister.github.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SVGs in Gatsby + React could be tricky. I would suggest using [`gatsby-plugin-react-svg`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-svg/) since it controls all the fallbacks. In your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: "gatsby-plugin-react-svg",
    options: {
      rule: {
        include: /svg/ 
      }
    }
  }
];
```

Note that the including rule is a regular expression. It means that `/svg/` folder is the folder path in all your project (i.e: if you have your SVGs inside `/src/assets/svg` in the plugin configuration must include only `/svg/`).

The rest of the configuration is similar to the one you've described:

```
import Icon from "./path/assets/icon.svg";

// ...

<Icon />;
```